# Extract single data point from multiple, webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract stock symbols (3rd column) from the table in below screener:

https://chartink.com/screener/2-short-trend
and pass them on to a dataframe.

Due to my limited knowledge, I have hit a wall and can not move past it.

My code is:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://chartink.com/screener/2-short-trend')
response.html.render()

for result in response.html.xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr/td/a[1]'):
    print(f'{result.text}\n')
```

Output:

```
Mahindra & Mahindra Limited

M&M

P&F

Apollo Tyres Limited

APOLLOTYRE

P&F

....
```

I just need stock symbols: M&M, APOLLOTYRE etc., and passed into a dataframe.

Can someone pls guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a quick fix, but you could use a counter assuming that the relevant output is the second result for every company.  Something like the below:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://chartink.com/screener/2-short-trend')
response.html.render()

i = 1
symbols = []
for result in response.html.xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr/td/a[1]'):
    print(f'{result.text}\n')
    if i == 2:
        symbols.append(result.text)
        i -= 2
    else:
        i += 1

df = pd.DataFrame({"Symbol": symbols})
```

I structured i to trigger appending the result to a symbols list at the position where the symbol is iterated over and then a dataframe is created using the output.  Using that code gave me a dataframe with the 5 symbols from your link.

Comment: Glad it helped!  Sorry, I’m not sure I totally follow on your second question.  Are you saying you just want to add an additional column with the string “exclude” in each row?  If that’s the case you can just add the line df[“column_name”] = “exclude” to the very bottom, where “column_name” is whatever you want to name it.